# How do I give non-google member webapp permission?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I've built a webapp (form) that I want others to be able to use. But when they access it, it askes to login to their Google account. I've already changed the settings so "anyone can access".

Is there a way to bypass this or authorize anyones accesss to the app so non-google users can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying, just make sure to choose the following:

1. `Execute as`: `Me (username@domain.com)`
2. `Who has access`: `Anyone`

If it still didn't worked, try to copy the GS code into a new file and then choose the following details above again. This seems to solve the same issue for some other users.